# How to deploy a django + django channels docker container in heroku?

Tags: django, heroku, django-rest-framework, django-channels

I have a dockerized django api backend hosted on heroku. I've used the heroku documentation to deploy the docker container `https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/container-registry-and-runtime`. Now I integrated django channels, it works fine locally after i followed the basic installation tutorial `https://channels.readthedocs.io/en/stable/installation.html`, but it doesn't work on heroku enviroment.

What is the best way to deploy a dockerized django channels to heroku?